# Workflow for forking an open source repository

Tags: git

I'm working on a product that is a fork of an open source repository (which I also maintain). My product is a super set of the open-source repository and is hosted as a private repo on Github.

Let's call the open-source repository "os" and my product's repository "prod".

I have both repos cloned on my dev machine. When I want to change "os", i enter that directory, do my changes, commit and push to Github. I then jump over to my "prod" directory, "git fetch os" and "git merge os/master".

This is starting to be very cumbersome. I'd much rather do the changes in "prod" and then push the commits over to "os". is this possible in some way?

Comment: Use github pull requests?

Comment: you "may" use git submodules.

Comment: Whoever thought this is off-topic, please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Git Submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules).
You can use OS as a submodule within Prod, keep making changes in OS, (and prod). When you're done, you push OS and Prod.